# Align two vertically-stacked rows of flex items next to one full-height flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I`m using flexbox and trying to make 6 things like this:
[image]

So far this is my code:

```
<section class="focus-item">
      <div class="item focus-item-1">
        <h4>Brand </h4>
        <p>Identity
          aliquam ipsum ante morbi sed ipsum mollis.
          Sollicitudin viverra, vel varius eget sit mollis.
        </p>
        <img src="D:/htmlCss/landing/assets/img/focus-item-1.png" alt="" />
      </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.focus-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.focus-item .item {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
}
.focus-item .item p {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.focus-item .item h4 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

I have problem with placing `h4` on top of `p`. I would be great if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/0j7abre9/ ? EDIT: An updated version where the text aligns to the right towards the picture: http://jsfiddle.net/0j7abre9/1/

Answer (score 2):

As I already posted it in my first comment, you can do it by making the first flex item a flex box as well:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item-1">
        <h4>Header</h4>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    </div>    
    <img src="https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/958_placeholders/placehold.gif" />
</div>

.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.item-1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

See here for the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/0j7abre9/1/

Answer (score 0):

The key to this layout is to create one flex container that holds two flex items – the first holding the `<h4>` and `<p>`, and the other holding the `<img>` – and align them in a `row`. Then convert the first flex item to a flex container as well, and align its two items in a `column`.

**HTML**

```
<section class="focus-item">
    <div class="item focus-item-1"><!-- nested flex container 1 -->
        <h4>Brand</h4>
        <p>Identity aliquam ipsum ante morbi sed ipsum mollis. 
           Sollicitudin viverra, vel varius eget sit mollis.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item focus-item-2"><!-- nested flex container 2 -->
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" height="200" width="200" alt="">
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.focus-item {
    display: flex;
}

.item {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 50%;
}

.focus-item-1 {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fyhxeLzs/1/)